# Webview can not load JavaScript Alert in android L devices

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I am using iFrame to load data to my application, In iFrame there is use of javascript alert.

javascript alert is working fine in all devices belongs to api < 20 but in api 20, alert is not working.

It is giving me logcat message like

> (Cannot create a dialog, the WebView context is not an Activity )

I have tried following code for this:

```
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.setClickable(true);
    webview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
    webview.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message,
                String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
            Log.d("jsPrompt:", "OK:" + url);
            return super.onJsPrompt(view, url, message, defaultValue,
                    result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                JsResult result) {
            Log.d("jsAlert:", "OK:" + url);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }
    };
    wvTourDetails.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

    if (url != null) {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Is there anyone, who can help me to use alert in android L Devices..

Thanks

Comment: How do you get the webview-object?

Comment: I have already define object in beginning of the onCreate() method

webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

Comment: This seems to be an Android 5 bug as I have seen another post with a bounty with the same issue, but there was no fix. The workarround is to make a JavaScript interface and show a dialog there.

Comment: I can not go through interface because data is loading from iFrame, which is on server

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Let me know if you find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this problem.

Google has updated Android System WebView to version 42 on 24th April,2015.

Update your Android System WebView to work with javascript in Android L device